# SQLDataAdapter changing value type returned from SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatadapter

In my C# project, I am executing a query against a SQL 2014 database to retrieve `Employee` data, including a `PeriodEnd` which is stored in the database as a `Decimal` (i.e., Nov 17, 2016 is stored as 20161117).  The database I am querying is not our product so I cannot change the type to a `DateTime` field.

Here is the SQL script being executed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.EMPLOYEE as EmpNo,
    ch.PEREND As PeriodEnd,
    ch.PRPOSTSTAT
FROM UPEMPL e
    INNER JOIN UPCHKH ch 
        ON e.EMPLOYEE = ch.EMPLOYEE
WHERE 
    ch.PEREND = @PERIODEND
```

Here is the `SqlDataAdapter` call:

```
ExecuteSqlCommandScript(String sqlScript, List<SqlParams> sqlParams)
{
    . . . (setup SqlConnection info)

    using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            _cmd.CommandText = sqlScript;
            _cmd.Connection = _conn;
            _cmd.Connection.Open();

            // add SqlParameters to SQL command
            if (sqlParams != null)
            {
                _cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());
            }

            using (SqlDataAdapter _sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd))
            {
               try
               {
                    // Save Table info to Results object
                    DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
                    _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet); 

                    SqlResult _result = new SqlResult();
                    _result.DataSet = _dataSet;
                    _result.TableCount = _dataSet.Tables.Count;

                    this.Results.Add(_result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using SQL Server Profiler I can see the query passed to SQL is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.EMPLOYEE as EmpNo,
    ch.PEREND As PeriodEnd,
    ch.PRPOSTSTAT
FROM UPEMPL e
    INNER JOIN UPCHKH ch 
        ON e.EMPLOYEE = ch.EMPLOYEE
WHERE 
    ch.PEREND = @PERIODEND 
',N'@PERIODEND nvarchar(8)',@PERIODEND=N'20161101'
```

If I run this directly in SQL these are the reults:

[image]

However, the results of the `DataTable` created by the `_sqlDataAdapter` is:

[image]

Is there a way to force `SqlDataAdapter` to use the data type as it is in the results?  Or is it possible that SQL is indeed returning a `DateTime` object instead of a `Decimal` (the `PeriodEnd` column is defined in SQL as `decimal(9,0)`)?  If so is there a reason for this and/or a way to prevent it?

Comment: What does `StartDate` have to do with this?

Comment: When you debug, what type does the compiler say? You could probably just do a `.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` on that column on each of the records.

Comment: Can you paste the code for the creation of the _cmd object. Particularly the creation of the command text and parameterisation?

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, what does `SELECT TOP(1) SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, PEREND), 'BaseType') FROM UPCHKH` yield?

Comment: @Crowcoder, Not sure why I wrote `StartDate`, have corrected this to `PeriodEnd`

Comment: @JeroenMostert running that script returns `decimal`

Comment: @DB101 I have update the post with the code you requested.

Comment: Well, then at least we've confirmed that `UPCHKH.PEREND` really is a `DECIMAL`. And I've just confirmed, just to make sure I'm not losing my marbles, that retrieving a `DECIMAL` column with value `20161101` through an `SqlDataAdapter` really will return it as a `Decimal` and not a `DateTime`. That leaves either the possibility of `_cmd` not being what you think it is, or `SqlResult` (which is not a framework class) altering the table before you see it, or `SqlDataAdapter` not being the framework class we know and love, or gremlins infesting your computer. (The latter may need refining.)

Comment: Thanks @BrianKE. Could you add the details where the parameter and values are assigned to sqlParams. I think they may be being assigned the incorrect datatype, hence profiler is showing them as nvarchar(8) as opposed to Decimal. This could then result in the implicit conversion of ther column to NVarchar(8).

Comment: @JeroenMostert what in `_cmd` might I look for as a possible cause?  `SqlResult` is a simple class with a `DataSet` and `TableCount` properties.  Many of our scripts return multiple dataset so we store them in a `List<SqlResult>`  `SqlDataAdapter` is the framework class from `System.Data.SqlClient` (.NET 4.5)

Comment: @DB101 The SQL call shows that the `PERIODEND` value is indeed being passed as nvarchar(8).  You can look at an earlier post of mine in which I tried to pass the `PERIODEND` as a `decimal` only to get the `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.` error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468272/sqldataadapter-fill-throwing-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-t

Comment: @BrianKE: anything in `_cmd` if it's not exactly identical to what you've posted as the command that shows up in the profiler trace. Actually, set a breakpoint on the code and see what `_cmd` contains prior to execution, and what `_dataset` contains before being added to `SqlResult`, and for that matter if `connectionString` is what you expect. Trust *nothing* at this stage.

Comment: OK

Things to check.

What happens under the following conditions:

Add a parameter to the comand using the following: 

_sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("PERIODEND", 20161101,DBType.Decimal));

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try and add the column type explicitly when you are creating the dataset , by adding datacolumn of type decimal to the datatable.
My guess is that since you are not explicitly specifying the column type, .net is deriving it from the value.

Comment: No. The data adapter derives the type from the type as returned by SQL Server. There is always such a type. It could be a `VARCHAR` or a `DECIMAL` or a `DATETIME`, but it's never something that makes .NET guess. What you are saying does apply to parameters -- if no type is specified, .NET has to derive the SQL type from the type of whatever object you're passing in, which may not match the type you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for explaing this @Jeroen Mostert

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help in this.  It was the suggestion to look at the `_cmd` object that lead me to the solution.  There was a piece of code that was supposed to change the database to use the database `ABC`.  This piece of code was not working properly and so the database connection stayed on database `XYZ`.  What made this so difficult to resolve is that database `XYZ` has views defined that return data from databse `ABC`, but with the `PeriodEnd` column as a `DateTime` and not a `decimal`.  I did not know about these views and when I saw data that matched what I expected, I didn't even think to look and make sure the database was correctly assigned.